# Rails ActiveRecord implementing relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, relationship, rails-migrations

Help me out with a db migration and model in Rails, I tried searching for self referencing and what not, but I can't make heads or tails.. I'm stuck, so to say..

Basically I want two models, User model and Rule model.

In User model I want to specify an owner of user, which is another user, there can only be one owner, user can be owner of itself.

And a  Rule model, in which I also want to specify an owner of a rule (User) (User can be an owner of many rules) and user to which this rule applies (User) (User can have many rules).

So I need two migrations and two models, I'll start and hopefully you'll be able to make out of what I'm trying to do ..

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user #?
  has_one :user    # as in owner
  has_many :rules  # rules for given user and rules that are created by this user
  ... #and some more similar entries
end
```

and

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user # as in owner of rule and rule for user
end
```

and I'm totally not sure what to write in migrations..

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username

      #owner?

      #stuff left out
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class CreateRules < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :rules do |t|
      t.string :title

      #rule for?
      #owner?

      #stuff left out
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is **Self referential association**

Read http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins and go through
[this episode on RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association). This demonstrates precisely what you are looking for.

Hope it helps

Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#Models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'owner_id'
  has_many :subordinates, :class_name => 'User'
  has_many :rules, :through => "owner_rules"
end
```

---

```
#Models/OwnerRule.rb
class OwnerRule < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :users
    belongs_to :rules
end
```

---

```
#Models/Rule.rb
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, :through => "owner_rules"
end
```

[**This rubyonrails guide**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many) has a good guideline on this.

So the point is, a `user` object will have two methods `owner` and `subordinates`.
If you call `user.owner` then it will return the user with **id** equals **user.owner_id**. 
If you call `user.subordinates` then it will return all users having the **user.id** in their **owner_id** column.

*Let me know if made it a bit convoluted or not :P*

Now, in case of migration scripts you will just create the columns as you named.

**UPDATE:**

Well if we just reorganize your requirements

- A user can have many Rules.
- Many rules can be applied to one user
- One user can have a Owner who is also a User
- One owner will have many subordinates who are User too.

Then ive updated my codes above. Please take a look if it helps now.

Comment: and what about Rule model? do I write it like this?

    `belongs_to :for, :class_name -> 'User', :foreign_key => 'user_id'` and `belongs_to :user` It references user two times.. as owner and as for (rule for)

also do I need to manually (in migration) create these fields?

Comment: "owner of rule" is a property of the rule (so a `belongs_to`) but a rule can apply to many users, and a user can have many rules applied, so it's a completely different thing.

Comment: If you write `belongs_to :user`, it will automatically derive the class name as **User** and `foreign_key` as 'user_id'. But in case of `belongs_to :owner` we have to specify the class name because the derived class name would be "Owner".

Answer (score 0):

You need three tables, because the "rule applied to user" is a many-to-many so it needs a join table.

You also need to rename either the "rule created by user" or the "rule applied to user" because otherwise you'll have name conflicts.

Tables:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      #stuff left out

      t.references :owner

      #stuff left out
    end
  end
end

class CreateRules < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :rules do |t|
      #stuff left out

      t.references :owner

      #stuff left out
    end
  end
end

class CreateRulesUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :rules_users do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :rule
    end
  end
end
```

Models

- User

  ```
  has_many :owned_users, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "owner_id", :inverse_of => :owner
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "owner_id", :inverse_of => :owned_users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :rules # uses the join table
  has_many :owned_rules, :class_name => "Rule", :foreign_key => "owner_id", :inverse_of => :owner
  ```
- Rule

  ```
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "owner_id", :inverse_of => :owned_rules
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users # uses the join table, it's the users to which the rule applies
  ```